# Show there exists an open ball that intersects a measurable set "enough"

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E$ be a Lebesgue-measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that its Lebesgue measure $m$ is non-zero, i.e. $m(E)>0$. Let $\alpha>1/2$. I am trying to prove that there exists an open ball $B$ such that
$$m(E\cap B)=\alpha m(B).$$
First of all, is this true? It seems intuitive; I am not even sure that the constraint $\alpha>1/2$ is needed.

The path that looks most promising to me is using density. Because $m(E)>0$ and for any measurable set almost every point is a density point, there exists some $x\in E$ such that $m(E\cap B_\varepsilon(x))\geq \alpha m(B_\varepsilon(x))$ for any $\alpha$ between zero and one. However I am not sure how to get the reverse inequality.

Please note that I would like to use this fact to give a proof of Steinhaus' theorem. Therefore I cannot use that result in the proof.

**EDIT:** I submited what I think is a proof below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if there's an easier proof, or if this one is OK. But with Dumper D Garb's help I found the following:

By the dominated convergence theorem, the function $r\mapsto m(A\cap B_r(x))$ is continuous for any measurable set $A$ and any point $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, with domain $[0,\infty]$. Therefore $g(r)=m(E\cap B_r(x))/m(B_r(x))$ is a continuous function (with domain $(0,\infty]$ since $m(B_r(x))=0$ if and only if $r=0$). Notice that for every $r$ and every $x$, $0\leq g(r)\leq 1$.

By a density theorem, almost every point of $E$ is a point of density. Since $m(E)>0$, there exists at least one such $x\in E$. Take this to be the "$x$" in the definition of $g$. Hence $g(r)\rightarrow 1$ as $r\rightarrow 0$ (this is just the definition of being a point of density). By continuity, there exists some $r>0$ such that $1/2<g(r)$; take $\alpha=g(r)$. So $m(E\cap B_r(x))=\alpha m(B_r(x))$ and by taking $B=B_r(x)$ we have proved the claim.